# What is the equivalent of ‍-h in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want convert `docker run` to `docker-compose` with `-h` parameter

What is the equivalent of ‍‍‍‍`-h` in `docker-compose`?

My `docker run` command:

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:80/tcp -p 1935:1935 -p 3478:3478 
-p 3478:3478/udp bigbluebutton -h webinar.mydomain.com
```

My `docker-compose`

```
version: "3"

services:
  bigbluebutton:
    build: .
    container_name: "bigbluebutton"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 1935:1935
      - 3478:3478
      - 3478:3478/udp
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      public:

networks:
  public:
    external:
      name: public
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct command? If you want `-h, --hostname string    Container host name`, then, you should not put `-h` after image.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that appears after the `docker run` image name is the Compose [`command:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#command).

```sh
docker run \
  --rm -p 8080:80/tcp -p 1935:1935 \  # Docker options
  -p 3478:3478 -p 3478:3478/udp \     # More Docker options
  bigbluebutton \                     # Image name
  -h webinar.mydomain.com             # Command
```

```yaml
services:
  bigbluebutton:
    build: .
    command: -h webinar.mydomain.com
    ports: ['8080:80', '1935:1935', '3478:3478', '3478:3478/udp']
```